# Нелёгкая задача с формой(сложно)

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[image: Форма которую нужно сделать]

**ВНИМАНИЕ, МОЖЕТ ЗАНЯТЬ МНОГО ВРЕМЕНИ И НЕРВОВ!**

При практике попалась интересная форма.
Не при фокусе там стоит подсказка, когда есть фокус подсказка изчезает и вводиться текст, когда текст введен подсказка снова появляется но то что мы вводили переходит на право, как с FORD

*Если есть какие вопросу, отвечу, помогите пожалуйста решит задачу*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function blurBrand() {
  var input = document.getElementById("brandInput");
  var span = document.getElementById("brandDisplay");
  span.textContent = input.value;
  input.value = "";
  input.placeholder = "Brand";
}

function focusBrand() {
  var input = document.getElementById("brandInput");
  input.placeholder = "";
}
```

```css
input {
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<input id="brandInput" type="text" placeholder="Brand" 
  onfocus="focusBrand()" onblur="blurBrand()"/>
<span id="brandDisplay"></span>
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы при фокусе подсказка исчезала

Comment: @Mr9S Она же исчезает...